# Is there any legit positive impact of LEGO on mental health?

Tags: safety

Is there any legit research done on the impact of LEGO on mental health?

For instance, does it positively affect kids’ mental development or does it help with stress, anxiety or any other mental-health issues?

Comment: If you go to google scholar and enter "LEGO positive effect" you will get a number of publications that describe exactly that. There are several studies that show all kinds of positive effects, not only on children. Creativity, teamwork, math, engineering, success, patience and other areas seem to be improved with LEGO.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.

Here is [a study](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=11160545183236639387) that demonstrates one way to use LEGO in ADHD counseling.

If you are looking for a more rigorous outcomes-focused methodology, there's [another study](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=15689337947352492110) that looked at the impact of LEGO on social skills development in children. It found significant improvement compared to the control in a pre-test, post-test study.

If your interested in the developmental side of LEGO, here's [a study](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=6401249819130581810) that shows a correlation between complex LEGO play in 3 and 4 year olds and their secondary school mathematics achievement.

On the adult side, here's [a study](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=1739000108721896446) that shows a decrease in workplace stress after a group LEGO activity.

I'm sure there are loads more, but that's what a quick search on Google Scholar turned up.